Can shap.DeepExplainer explain combination of two models?
I have trained autoencoder and DNN models to my dataset. The autoencoder reduces the dimension of input data and then passes it to the DNN model for binary classification. I would like to understand the feature importance of the root variables in the prediction.
As per the answer to this question, I have wrapped the encoder model and DNN model and used shap.DeepExplainer to explain this model.
class ModelWrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, first_dnn_ml_model, dnn_ml_model):
        super(ModelWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.first_dnn_ml_model = first_dnn_ml_model
        self.dnn_ml_model = dnn_ml_model

    def forward(self, X):   
        X_first_dnn = self.first_dnn_ml_model(X)
        X_dnn = self.dnn_ml_model(X_first_dnn)
        return torch.sigmoid(X_dnn)

For five-fold cross-validation, I have computed shap value for test data as follows:
shap_value_array = [] 

for count in range(5): 
    modelwrapper = ModelWrapper(first_dnn_model, second_dnn_model) 
    explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(modelwrapper, X_train[:100].to(device)) 
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test.to(device)) 
    shap_value_array.append(shap_values)  
    
shap_value_array_stacked = np.vstack(shap_value_array)  

Is my approach correct to get the feature importance of the root variables in the prediction.? I think there are some discrepancies. Because, when I draw summary plot, I found that all features are negatively impacting models prediction.
shap.summary_plot(shap_value_array_stacked , X_test, plot_type="bar", feature_names=np.arange(len(X_test[0])))
shap.plots.force(explainer.expected_value, shap_value_array_stacked ) 


What is the correct way to treat these two models together as a system of models and perform SHAP on top of both of these to retrieve the feature importance of the raw variable?
